# Is the href="" function the same as include?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to ask you something about `href` in HTML and `include` in PHP. What is the difference between `href` and `include`, they both refer to a file path? When I type `<link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style1.css' />` it means that "you can find `style.css` file at folder named `style` at your current position and so on for the include. If you can be more specific I will appreciated it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a different question. If you have a new question, then post a new question.

Comment: oh okay. sorry for that. im new here. and i have only 1 question to ask a day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

href is not a file path, it's a URL, you use it to direct to another page.

include in PHP actually includes a separate file at that point in the page. Let's say you're building a php flat file site. Your header and footer are always the same but the pages change. You could include the header and footer as separate files instead of typing their code into each page.

```
<?php
  include 'header.php';
  //the rest of your page code goes here.
  include 'footer.php';
```

Comment: okay.so if i write a code like this `<link rel='stylesheet' href='c:/windows/xampp/test-web/css/style1.css' />` is it wrong ?, since you say that href is URL.

Comment: link does include a file but in a different way, but you absolutely want to use a relative URL there not an absolute one. /css/style1.css should work fine. Since when using xampp the root of your project would be test-web

Comment: i know it is different. can you tell me what the difference is with more specific explanation ?. because when i use `<link rel='stylesheet' href='c:/windows/xampp/test-web/css/style1.css' />`, my web page will load without any styling. *edited: its occured when i open it on web server.

Comment: Read what I wrote above about relative URL. If I remember right Xampp doesn't even know anything above test-web exists. Your css stylesheet lives at <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style1.css' /> as far as Xampp is concerned, because it's not reading your local file system, it is pointing to a URL relative to the web root. Your web root in this case is test-web.

Comment: So xampp only read files at my webroot, not outside "the root". thanks it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

'href' will redirect to the specific page when it has clicked or triggered.

'include' is used to get the code from the another file and place it on the called file to use functions and variables